# Show facebook page posts only in android Webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load facebook page posts in android Webview.
I am loading

> https://touch.facebook.com/pg/PAGE_NAME/posts/

But when its loading there is always showing login option.
What I want to show,

1. Only posts will be showing of a page without any header or login option. or
2. No login option will not be showing. or
3. Scroll to a position where feed will be at device screen top

How can I achieve any from above three (1 will be more appreciated)?

Comment: You would need to request the posts via API and then display them yourself. That of course requires an access token - and if you don’t want to use user access tokens on the client (that would require the user to login to your app), then you have to do this server-side, using your app access token or a page access token (both of which should not be exposed in client-side code.)

Answer (score 0):

You required access token for that and without login you can not get Access token. You has do one time login then Access Token is saved in cache and help to access post without Login. and another way is if you use `fblogin_button.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_ONLY);` and Facebook app is installed with login then there is no need of Login

Answer (score 0):

After trying for many hours I think I got something different,
From [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) you can generate customized view iframe and then you can load it inside html body tag. No login option will be shown at top, it will be only page view. Also no access token or login required to remove top login option.

As I am trying to load in Webview so I think its the way I should go.